# C# Regex pattern for getting resolution from string

Tags: c#, regex, string

Im new in C#, I have the following string, want to extract resolution from it string could be any length.

e.g.

```
1100x1200@60
```

or

```
800x600@25
```

and I want to extract `1100` and `1200` in two different variables using regular expression.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below regex and grab the resolution values from group index 1 and 2.

```
@"(\d+)x(\d+)"
```

You may add lookahead to check the match the resolution only if it's followed by an `@` symbol.

```
@"(\d+)x(\d+)(?=@)"
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/lZ5mN8/50)

```
String input = @"1100x1200@60";
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"(\d+)x(\d+)(?=@)");
foreach (Match m in rgx.Matches(input))
{
String var1 = m.Groups[1].Value;
String var2 = m.Groups[2].Value;
Console.WriteLine(var1);
Console.WriteLine(var2);
}
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/BPBBhV)

Comment: I tried what you have suggested but it returns @60 instead of 1100 and 1200 
I did by following way 
private static readonly Regex ResolutionPartRegex = new Regex(@"(\d+)x(\d+)"); 
resolution ="1100x1200@60" 
var width = resolution.Substring(ResolutionPartRegex.Match(resolution).Length);

Comment: it works for me . see the ideone link. and you need to print the group index 1 and 2, not index 0.

Comment: I created application and tried but it doesn't return the same. can you please post the code.

Comment: code is on the ideone link. could you provide the exact input? or post your code in ideone and then send back the link to me.

Comment: I tried and now its working. :) but when same string i.e @"(\d+)x(\d+)(?=@)" I posted on http://regex101.com/r/lZ5mN8/49, it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

```
([^x]+)x([^@]+)
```

Try this.Grab the capture.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/lZ5mN8/49